# ffmpeg keyframe control on single image + audio

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I have scoured every related StackOverflow question I can find and none of them solved the issue, apologies in advance if I missed the one that would have worked.

The application I am working on converts a video or audio file to an mp4, and later on the server to an hls playlist. I just implemented audio and I wanted a background image. After reading through various options on StackOverflow I settled on the following args:

```
-y -i "C:\path\ExternalAudioBackground.png" -i "C:\path\Audio.mp3" -vf scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black -c:a copy -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p "C:\path\external_media_file.mp4"
```

This set of args was chosen because it is instantaneous due to `-c:a copy` as well as constraints to ensure all videos have the same aspect ratio and encoding.

The issue is when converting this to an hls stream the stream fails to play (in video.js player, and also vlc) with the message :

VIDEOJS: WARN: Segment with index 0 from playlist 0-https://domain/video.m3u8 has a duration of 464.96 when the reported duration is 0.04 and the target duration is 0.04. For HLS content, a duration over the target duration may result in playback issues. See the HLS specification section on EXT-X-TARGETDURATION for more details: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-23#section-4.3.3.1 https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-23#section-4.3.3.1

Adding `-loop 1` to the start increases the processing time from milliseconds to minutes, but produces a working file

Adding `-r 1 and -loop 1` takes longer to process than without `-r` (!?)

Adding `-stream_loop 116` (116 is the length of the audio in seconds divided by 4, the desired hls segment size) before the image input loops the first 4 seconds of the audio over and over

adding `-g 96` (96 is the fps * 4)

In case relevant, the hls encoding arguments look like this:

```
-safe 0 -f concat -i listOfFiles.txt -c:a aac -ar 48000 -b:a 128k -vcodec copy -crf 20 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -sc_threshold 0 -b:v 2500k -maxrate 2675k -bufsize 3750k -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod  -hls_segment_filename segment-%03d.ts result.m3u8
```

listOfFiles.txt always contains only one file in the case being discussed.

How can I achieve this with the minimum processing time but still have the file convertable to HLS?

Comment: Add `-loop 1 -framerate 0.5` before the image input and `-intra`  after `libx264`

Comment: In your HLS command, `-crf 20 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -sc_threshold 0 -b:v 2500k -maxrate 2675k -bufsize 3750k` have no effect. Remove them.

Comment: @Gyan after that ran for an hour I killed the process. It reached time 787minutes in the output. The mp3 is 7 minutes.

Comment: Add `-shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 100M` as well.

Comment: @Gyan awesome that works well now. If you want to post that in an answer for the rep I will mark it as accepted. If you don't care I can self answer. I would love an explanation of what the different flags do to solve the problem though if you have the time. I understand some of them but understanding how to use ffmpeg is vastly superior to copy pasting other people's code, as you showed with the HLS command in your second comment. The ones I specifically do not yet understand are -intra -fflags -max_interleave...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Gyan for solving this in comments:

Add -loop 1 -framerate 0.5 before the image input and -intra after libx264

Add -shortest -fflags +shortest -max_interleave_delta 100M